# ¿Cómo comprimir archivos adjuntos al correo y encriptarlos? PHP

Tags: php, php5, phpmailer

El código *PHP* me funciona muy bien para enviar el correo electrónico, pero desaría comprimir todo y encriptarlos.

He visto  unas librerías para esto como (`phpzip` y `ziparchive`) o (`php-encryption`), y no llego a incluirlos ahí.

Código:

```
<?php

    $Nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $Mensaje = $_POST['Mensaje'];
    $Telefono = $_POST['Telefono'];
    $archivo = $_FILES['adjunto'];
    $archivo2 = $_FILES['adjunto2'];
    $archivo3 = $_FILES['adjunto3'];

    if ($Nombre=='' || $Email=='' || $Mensaje=='' || $Telefono==''){

        echo "<script>alert('Los campos marcados con * son obligatorios');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";

    }else{

        require("archivosformulario/class.phpmailer.php");
        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        $mail->From     = $Email;
        $mail->FromName = $Nombre; 
        $mail->AddAddress("miemail@gmail.com"); // Dirección a la que llegaran los mensajes.

        // Aquí van los datos que apareceran en el correo que reciba
        //adjuntamos un archivo 

        $mail->WordWrap = 50; 
        $mail->IsHTML(true);     
        $mail->Subject  =  "Contacto";
        $mail->Body     =  "Nombre: $Nombre \n<br />".    
        "Email: $Email \n<br />".    
        "Mensaje: $Mensaje \n<br />".
        "Telefono: $Telefono \n<br />";
        $mail->AddAttachment($archivo['tmp_name'], $archivo['name']);
        $mail->AddAttachment($archivo2['tmp_name'], $archivo2['name']);
        $mail->AddAttachment($archivo3['tmp_name'], $archivo3['name']);

        // Datos del servidor SMTP

        $mail->IsSMTP(); 
        $mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465";  // Servidor de Salida.
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
        $mail->Username = "miemail@gmail.com";  // Correo Electrónico
        $mail->Password = "pass"; // Contraseña

        if ($mail->Send())
        echo "<script>alert('Formulario enviado exitosamente, le responderemos lo más pronto posible.');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";
        else
        echo "<script>alert('Error al enviar el formulario');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para comprimir los ficheros yo haría algo así:

```
$archive_file_name = 'ficheros.zip';
$file_path = "C:\tmp\";

$pathZip = $file_path . $archive_file_name;

$zip = new ZipArchive();

//Creamos el fichero
if ($zip->open($pathZip, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$archive_file_name>\n");
}

//Agregamos los ficheros en el zip
foreach ($files_names as $file) {
    $dest = $file_path.$file;
    $zip->addFile($dest,$file);
}

$zip->close();
```

En cuanto a la encriptación, yo lo que haría sería encriptar el contenido de los ficheros con [openssl_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/es/function.openssl-encrypt.php). Puedes obtener más información [aquí](http://php.net/openssl).

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestarme, lo voy a pruebar ahorra ,lo unico que estoy con mac .Entonces seria cambiar C:\tmp\ por /users/andros/tmp ? No se muy bien, Gracias

Comment: O simplemente /tmp ?

Comment: Me olvide decir que mi script va dirido en un hosting , lo diseñe en locahost si , pero al momento de subirlo el ($file_path = "C:\tmp\";) ? Porfavor si me puedes indicar el /tmp/ de un hosting y mac os .Muchas Gracias de antemano

Comment: Buenas, el directorio que he puesto es simplemente uno de prueba. Puedes poner cualquier directorio al que tengas acceso. Dependerá del sistema operativo de tu hosting. Un saludo.